# Getting month from UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, uipickerview

I have a unique requirement. In my app I need to get only the month from picker. Since Date picker cannot implement this, I made the custom picker listing only months. The required format of the date after the customer selects a month is 1-Jan-2011 to 1-feb-2011

Basically, the month is the only thing that is coming from uipickerview and the day and year are static.
Can someone help me out? Some code I have tried.

```
    NSString *dateString = [[NSString alloc ]initWithFormat:@"2011-%d-1 GMT+05:30", monthFromPickerAsInteger];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        // this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
        // if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yy-MM-DD z4"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        // ta-daaa!
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    NSLog(@"%@", dateFromString);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to do this,

```
NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2011-%d-1", monthFromPickerAsInteger];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-M-d"]; 
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d-MMM-yyyy"];
NSString *requiredDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
[dateFormatter release];    

NSLog(@"%@", requiredDateString);
```